# Woocommerce force free shipping if you are admin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I currently have free shipping on items over $75, but if an admin login and place an order. I want the admin to have free shipping regardless if the cart is not over $75. I've been trying to use the following code, but it's not triggering it. Am I doing something wrong?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'show_free_shipping', 10, 2 );
function show_free_shipping( $rates, $package ) {
    global $current_user;
    $free = array();
    foreach ( $rates as $rate_id => $rate ) {
        if ( 'free_shipping' === $rate->method_id ) {
            if ($current_user->ID) {
                $user_roles = $current_user->roles;
                $user_role = array_shift($user_roles);

                if ($user_role == 'administrator') {
                    $free[ $rate_id ] = $rate;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return ! empty( $free ) ? $free : $rates;
    //return $rates;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the filter `woocommerce_package_rates` is used after that the free shipping is set has "not available" because the minimum is not reached.

to make the free shipping available again, you can use the filter `woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available`
https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Shipping_Free_Shipping.html#200-202

try this :

```
add_filter("woocommerce_shipping_free_shipping_is_available"
    , function ($is_available, $package, $method)
{


    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    if (in_array("administrator", $current_user->roles)) {
        $is_available = TRUE;
    }


    return $is_available;

}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Thank you, so much.. I've been at hours trying to figure it out.